# Listview background issues

Tags: ios, listview, nativescript, nativescript-vue

How do you change the white background of the Listview.
If you pull on the list you see a white background, there also a little white border on the bottom of the listview. In Android we don't have that what do I need to change to don't see that white border?

Details see gif. Android picture is under the gif. Code of the Listview is at the bottom.

[image]

[image: Android image]

```
<FlexboxLayout dock="center" class="menu-center" separatorColor="#1a0dab">
     <ListView for="(item, index) in languages" ref="listview" @itemTap="onItemTap" @itemLoading="onItemLoading">
             <v-template>
                 <FlexboxLayout class="element">
                     <Label class="top-text" :text="item.nameNative"></Label>
                 </FlexboxLayout>
             </v-template>
     </ListView>
</FlexboxLayout>


.menu-center{
        flex-direction: column;
    }

.menu-center .element{
        padding-top: 20%;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #1a0dab;
}
```

Comment: Try setting a background color on the ListView itself.

Comment: Thanks, why didn't I tried that. I almost tried everything beside that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Manoj

Adding background-color to the `ListView` itself

```
<FlexboxLayout dock="center" class="menu-center" separatorColor="#1a0dab">
    <ListView for="(item, index) in languages" ref="listview" class="listView" @itemTap="onItemTap" @itemLoading="onItemLoading">
        <v-template>
            <FlexboxLayout class="element">
                <Label class="top-text" :text="item.nameNative"></Label>
            </FlexboxLayout>
        </v-template>
    </ListView>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

```css
.menu-center .listView{
    background-color: #1a0dab;
}
```